# Update a Column with a like and a concat

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: animal and espece(fr='species'). 
In animal I have a column named espece_id, in which I want to fill data with espece.id (primary key) and I try to do this:

```
UPDATE animal
SET espece_id = espece.id
WHERE espece LIKE concat('%', espece.name, '%');
```

table details:

```
animal: id, espece, espece_id
espece: id, name, scientific_name
```

`animal.espece` and `espece.name` are equal to some extent like: "dog" "eurasian sheperd dog" so that's why I try to use a LIKE in this update, but it gives a:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'espece.name' in 'where clause'

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your SQL statement is confusing. The column name and table name are the same.

Comment: Well its not mine, it's an exercise I got at school :D. For the information  the solution given (by the professor) for this exercise is a simple update with multiple set for every possible value, I'm just trying to do it in a "simpler" manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a JOIN:

```
UPDATE animal AS a
JOIN espece AS e ON a.espece LIKE concat('%', e.name, '%')
SET a.espece_id = e.id
```